Elastic Pool database moving to another subscription
We have requirement for application which is currently in shared model and customer decided to migrate separately into different azure subscription.Current infra do has SQL Elastic Pool.
Now We dba must establish new SQL Elastic Pool along with new app plan and migrate both SQL Databases and apps.
How should be the approach to migrate this SQL Elastic pool databases onto the new azure subscription,and how do we perform the final cutover onto the new azure subscription.Can we establish a continuous data replication onto the new subscription to minimize downtime during cutover.
Thanks in advance.

Have you tried the Move button from the portal?


From the portal log in into the Resource Group that contains your resources.
select one or more resources that you want to move
Select the target Resource Group or Subscription

The portal will now tell you a list of Resources that can or cannot be moved.
Take your decisions based on that check.
